# If $f(z)$ maps the unit disk onto itself $k$ times, prove that $f(z)$ must be a rational function and that the degree of its denominator $\leq k$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(x)$ be an analytic function which is defined in the open unit disk ($|z| < 1$). $f(z)$ maps the unit disk onto itself $k$ times,so $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $|z| < 1$ and every point in the unit disk has k pre-images under $f(z)$. Prove that f(z) must be a rational function and show that the degree of its denominator cannot exceed $k$.

How do we even proceed with this question? I feel like there is a theorem I'm forgetting or haven't learned that is necessary to solve this question. As a first attempt to understand the functions we're looking for, it seems like the function
$$
f(z) = z^k
$$
satisfies the required criteria. But this is an obvious guess. Are there other functions and why should they even be rational?

EDIT: $z^k$ does not work as pointed out in the comments. Another thought is that 
$$
\frac{z-a}{\overline a z - 1}
$$
for $|a|<1$ maps the unit disk onto itself. It was suggested in the comments to look at a product of terms like this, but again, what does that get us toward a solution?

Comment: 0 does not have $k$ preimages so you need something else. Have you looked at modifying the Mobius map? Consider $f(z)=\frac{e^{i \theta}(z-a)^m}{(1- \bar {a}z)^n}$ for $\vert a\vert<1$

Comment: @Chilango. Good point about the origin. Can you explain your suggestion and why that should work for $f(z)$? I've seen something similar called the Blaschke product, but not in relation to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has $k$ distinct roots $a_1,...,a_k$. Using the proposed Möbius factors you can construct a rational function with the same roots satisfying the assumptions put onto $f$,
$$
g(z)=\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{z-a_k}{1-z\bar a_k}.
$$
Now argue that $f(z)/g(z)$ is still a holomorphic function, maps the disk into itself and has no roots.